# Transform JavaScript object by clearing, adding and removing properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, key-value

Here are the instructions for what I am supposed to do:

> Implement a function accepting 2 arguments: `state` and `actions`. The
> function should change the `state` basing on the given `actions`
> array.
>
> - `state` is an object. You are supposed to add, change, or delete its   properties instead of creating a new object
> - `actions` is an array of objects. Each object in this array has the next properties:
>
>   - `type` contains a string: either `'addProperties'`, `'removeProperties'` or `'clear'`;
>   - The second property of each object depends on `type` and may be one of the following:
>
>     - if `type` is `addProperties`, second property is `extraData`. It contains an object
>       with `key: value` pairs to add to the state;
>     - if `type` is `removeProperties`, second property is `keysToRemove`. It contains an array
>       with the list of property names (keys) to remove from the `state`; (Not existing
>       properties should be ignored)
>     - if `type` is `clear` you should remove all the properties from the
>       state. No second property in this case;
>
> Example of usage:
>
> If `state` is `{foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'}`, then
>
> ```
>  transformState(state, [
>    {
>      type: 'addProperties',
>      extraData: {
>        name: 'Jim',
>        hello: 'world',
>      }
>    },
>    {
>      type: 'removeProperties',
>      keysToRemove: ['bar', 'hello'],
>    },
>    {
>      type: 'addProperties',
>      extraData: { another: 'one' },
>    }
>  ])
> ```
>
> should modify the `state`, doing the following:
>
> - add two properties to the `state`
> - then remove keys `bar` and `hello` from the `state`
> - and finally add another one property to the `state`
>
> After these operations the object `state` will have the following look
>
> ```
>  {
>    foo: 'bar',
>    name: 'Jim',
>    another: 'one',
>  }
> ```
>
> Another example:
>
> ```
>  const state = { x: 1 };
>
>  transformState(state, [
>    { type: 'addProperties', extraData: { yet: 'another property' } }
>    { type: 'clear' },
>    { type: 'addProperties', extraData: { foo: 'bar', name: 'Jim' } }
>  ]);
>
> state === { foo: 'bar', name: 'Jim' }
> ```

Here is my code so far:

```
function transformState(state, actions) {
  const transformedState = state;

  for (const { type } of actions) {
    if (type === 'clear') {
      Object.keys(transformedState)
        .forEach(key => delete transformedState[key]);
    } else if (type === 'addProperties') {
      for (const { extraData } of actions) {
        for (const data in extraData) {
          transformedState[data] = extraData[data];
        }
      }
    } else if (type === 'removeProperties') {
      for (const { keysToRemove } of actions) {
        for (const item in keysToRemove) {
          delete transformedState[keysToRemove[item]];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return transformedState;
}
```

It works with almost all scenarios, but it doesn't remove some properties and I can not figure out why. The 2 test it won't pass:

```
test('Should apply several types', () => {
  const state = {
    foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo',
  };

  transformState(state, [
    {
      type: 'addProperties',
      extraData: {
        name: 'Jim', hello: 'world',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'removeProperties', keysToRemove: ['bar', 'hello'],
    },
    {
      type: 'addProperties', extraData: { another: 'one' },
    },
  ]);

  expect(state)
    .toEqual({
      foo: 'bar', name: 'Jim', another: 'one',
    });
});

test('Should work with a long list of types', () => {
  const state = {
    foo: 'bar', name: 'Jim', another: 'one',
  };

  transformState(state, [
    {
      type: 'removeProperties', keysToRemove: ['another'],
    },
    { type: 'clear' },
    { type: 'clear' },
    { type: 'clear' },
    {
      type: 'addProperties', extraData: { yet: 'another property' },
    },
    { type: 'clear' },
    {
      type: 'addProperties',
      extraData: {
        foo: 'bar', name: 'Jim',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'removeProperties', keysToRemove: ['name', 'hello'],
    },
  ]);

  expect(state)
    .toEqual({ foo: 'bar' });
});
```

In the first test in the add properties section, if I change the order of "hello" and "name", it still only removes name and I can't figure out why. Here is the test output:

```
● Should apply several types                                    
                                                                  
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
        "another": "one",
        "foo": "bar",
    -   "name": "Jim",
    +   "hello": "world",
      }

      196 |
      197 |   expect(state)
    > 198 |     .toEqual({
          |      ^
      199 |       foo: 'bar', name: 'Jim', another: 'one',        
      200 |     });
      201 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/transformState.test.js:198:6)    

  ● Should work with a long list of types

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
        "foo": "bar",
    +   "yet": "another property",
      }

      229 |
      230 |   expect(state)
    > 231 |     .toEqual({ foo: 'bar' });
          |      ^
      232 | });
      233 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/transformState.test.js:231:6)
```

Comment: You shouldn't nest those `for` loops, you'll need to use the `extraData` that belongs to the respective - *current* - `addProperties` action, and use the `keysToRemove` that belong to the *current* `removeProperties` action. Try starting with `for (const action of actions) if (action.type == …) …`

Comment: Yeah that worked, it was also a lot shorter, thank you!!